# How to top center align text inside a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, nodes, tikzpagenodes

This is what my nodes look like:

[image]

I would like to have all the text to be aligned at the top of each node.
This is the code:

```
\node[rec5, below=4.6cm of E] (G) {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde};
\node[rec5, below=4.6cm of E1] (G1) {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen
Stunde, entsprechend typischer Woche im Monat};
\node[rec5, below=4.6cm of E2] (G2) {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen
Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Monat};
\node[rec5, below=4.6cm of E3] (G3) {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen
Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Quartal};
```

with rec5 being:

```
\tikzstyle{rec5}=[minimum width=4.05cm,minimum height=6cm, draw, outer sep=0pt, align=center, anchor=north, text width=3.7cm, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt]
```

I somehow couldn't find anything like this on here but I am certain someone must have had the same question before.. anyhow I am happy about any hints!

EDIT:

This is part of a bigger flowchart with various paths so i absolutely need to do it in nodes i think.

here's another snippet:
[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal example.

Comment: This can be relative simple achieved by table. Is use of `tikz` package obligatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not  entirely clear. Missed is context of nodes, are use of `tikz` image with your nodes obligatory, etc. As I mentioned in comment, those four nodes can be simple replaced by table, for example. For example by using `tabularray package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec = {X[j] c X[j] c X[j] c X[j] c X[j] c },
             column{even} = {colsep=2pt},
             colsep=3pt,
             }
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde
    &   \SetCell[r=1]{j}
        & Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde, entsprechend typischer Woche im Monat
        &   \SetCell[r=1]{j}
            & Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Monat
            &   \SetCell[r=1]{j}
                &  Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Quartal      \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After editing the context of problem is clarified. Possible solution (which encourage to use decent `tikz` syntax) can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    rec5/.style = {draw,
                   text depth = #1\baselineskip, text width=34mm, align=center, inner sep=1mm}
        }

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2em and 2mm
                        ]
% simulate part of diagram above nodes of concer
\coordinate (E);
\coordinate[right=38mm of E]    (E1);
\coordinate[right=38mm of E1]   (E2);
\coordinate[right=38mm of E2]   (E3);
    \begin{scope}[rec5/.default = 9]
\node[rec5, below=of E] (G) 
    {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde};
\node[rec5, below=of E1] (G1) 
    {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen
Stunde, entsprechend typischer Woche im Monat};
\node[rec5, below=of E2] (G2) 
    {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen
Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Monat};
\node[rec5, below=of E3] (G3) 
    {Umwandlung der Zustände in normierte Lastwerte durch Sampling der GMM für den jeweiligen Zustand in der jeweiligen Stunde, entsprechend dem Tagtyp im Quartal};
\draw[->]   (E)  edge (G)
            (E1) edge (G1)
            (E2) edge (G2)
            (E3)  to  (G3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: sorry ill update the whole thing for context

Comment: @Stefan44, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

i figured that adding the `text depth` parameter does the trick, e.g.

```
\tikzstyle{rec5}=[minimum width=4.05cm,minimum height=6cm, draw, outer sep=0pt, align=center, text width=3.7cm, inner xsep=0pt,text depth = 5.75 cm]
```